# why do I get "reason is: this server does not require authentication" in xpra

Tags: x11, xorg, remote

I 'd like to use `Xpra` as described on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xpra. However, I'm using the Xpra Windows client to connect but it doesn't work & and I keep getting an error message "this server does not require authentication" where in my xpra logfile it says:

```
$ tail -f .xpra/:30.log 
2016-01-25 13:52:24,277 New connection received: SocketConnection(/home/ron/.xpra/jpax-build07-30) 
2016-01-25 13:52:24,279 Disconnecting existing client Protocol(SocketConnection(/home/ron/.xpra/jpax-build07-30)), reason is: this server does not require authentication 
2016-01-25 13:52:24,279 Connection lost 2016-01-25 13:52:24,281 Connection lost
```

Why is  this I'm wondering? I've googled around but couldn't find any helpful information...

Comment: You should specify how you start your server and client, the exact command lines. It is impossible to help you without it. In any case, stackexchange is not the best place to get help for xpra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is too old: the version from the Ubuntu repositories is very old and buggy.

You client is providing authentication credentials and the server doesn't need them, older servers rejected the connection, newer ones will log a warning and continue.

Comment: Thanks, yah, I'd long resolved this but never updated the question. Thanks anyways!